# How to split my data from a database into several option tags for my dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have been struggling with this issue for weeks, My data just lists all the players in one option tag when I want the data to split into multiple option tags. Please help me you geniuses!! (Node.js noob)

------------------------------ CODE -------------------------------------

------- APP.JS -------

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


    // get PLAYERS for dropdown in 'create a team'
    app.get('/getData_players',function(req,res){
    
        // connect to the db
        var mysql = require('mysql')
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : '',
            port         : 3306,
            database : 'mgp'
    
        });
    
        connection.connect();
        connection.query('SELECT * from players', function (err, rows, fields) {
            // ensuring to throw something whether there's an error or not
            if(err) throw err;
    
            var output = '';
            for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++){
    
                var player = rows[i].player + '<br> ';
                    output += player.split();
                    console.log(output);
            }
            console.log("Connected to player table!");
            res.send(output);
        });
        connection.end();
    });
    
    
    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      next(createError(404));
    });
    
    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
    
      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });
    
    module.exports = app;
```

------- INDEX.EJS -------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/themes/RED.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- TEAM -->
<div data-role="page" id="four" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Team</h1>

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2>Create a team</h2>

        <form action="app.js" method="get">
            GK<select onclick="getData_players()" id="goal_keeper" /> <option class="player_data"></option></select>

            RB <select id="right_back"/> <option onclick="getData_players()"> </option> </select>
            CB <select id="center_back_1"/></select>
            CB <select id="center_back_2"/></select>
            LB<select id="left_back"/></select>
            RM <select id="right_mid"/></select>
            CM <select id="center_mid_1"/></select>
            CM <select id="center_mid_2"/></select>
            LM <select id="left_mid"/></select>
            ST<select id="striker1"/></select>
            ST<select id="striker2"/></select>
            <button id = "submitTeam"class="ui-btn">Submit Team</button>
        </form>

        <p><a href="#one" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b">Logout</a></p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page cook -->

<!-- SHOW PLAYERS DROPDOWN -->
<script>
    function getData_players(){
        $.get("/getData_players", function (data)
        {
            $(".player_data").html(data);
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(".player_data")` IS an `<option>`. You need to create an `<option>` for each player. You are just sending a big long string. Also note that events don't work cross browser on `<option>` elements. You have an `<option onclick="getData_players()">` that will fail in some browsers

Comment: Hi thank you for replying! So are you saying I should use a for loop for based on the data's length to give me the necessary options?

Comment: Yes. Either server side to generate html ( lots of `<option>` in string), or send json array to client side and create them there

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, Do you know where I can find any examples how to execute these techniques as I'm pretty new to this language

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
connection.query('SELECT * from players', function (err, rows, fields) {
            // ensuring to throw something whether there's an error or not
            if(err) throw err;
    
            var output = '';
            const players = rows.map((row) => row.player);
            console.log("Connected to player table!");
            res.render('./index', players);
        });
```

HTML

```
<% players.forEach((player) => { %>
  <option class="player_data"><%=player%></option>

  <%})%>
```

THIS IS TO ADDRESS LATER COMMENTS

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I attempted that code but I'm getting errors like "players is not defined"

Comment: Hey I made a slight tweak. You may need to render and pass in the players. Can you do a console.log before you execute res.render or res.json and tell me what it says.

Comment: I added the re-edited version but the page just says "players is not defined", Should I add the html code where the select tags are or in the script tag with the function name "getDataPlayers()"? thanks

Comment: Hmm, I was just looking up some stuff and the reason that code isnt working for me is because for some reason, the ASP syntax wont work on my web app

Comment: Could you share your package.json or public GitHub repo?

Comment: Heres a link to the project: https://github.com/markaigbe/wepapp, the read.me file has some steps to get the project to run, thanks

Comment: In the future your repo should have the source code not a zip file.

Comment: you are not handling EJS correctly. response.write is not a valid function. When you send data from the router in express, in EJS file you just need to reference it.

Comment: Update answer, if you found this helpful please approve my answer! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, did the dropdown work for you? Im so slow at this sorry

Comment: I didn’t run your code. However, if you follow the EJS documentation and express you’ll be okay.